# Java JPasswordField

Tags: java, jpasswordfield

So I have to write a program that prompts the user to enter a password that has to follow three requirements: at least 8 characters long, only letters and digits, and at least two digits. Now the method I created to check these three requirements I believe is sound, but my program also has to do some exception handling and be able to ask the user to reenter the password if one of the requirements is off and display the respective error message to go along with each requirement. I created a string errorMessage to relay that message but it gives me an error when i try to call it in my main ?

My other issue is that the password must be taken in to my program by using JPasswordField but I am struggling with even setting it up because of the numerous other factors like the JPanel, buttons, and action events that I read has to go along with it. I attempted to use JPasswordField and noticed that the line that takes in the password, takes it in as an array, when my checkPassword method needs a string, how can i take in that password as a string instead?

This is what I have for my program so far:

```
   import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
   import javax.swing.JFrame;
   import javax.swing.JLabel;
   import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
   import javax.swing.JPasswordField;

   import javafx.event.ActionEvent;

public class Ed10Chp6Ex6Point18CheckPasswordProgram {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Check Password Program");
    JLabel jlbPassword = new JLabel("Please enter the password: ");
    JPasswordField jpwName = new JPasswordField(15);
    jpwName.setEchoChar('*');
    jpwName.addActionListener(new ActionListener()) {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JPasswordField input = (JPasswordField) e.getSource();
            char[] password = input.getPassword();

            if(checkPassword(password)){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Congradulations, your password follows all the requirements");
            }
            else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, errorMessage);
            }
        }
    }
}

public static boolean checkPassword(String x) {

    String errorMessage = "";

    //must have at least eight characters
    if (x.length() < 8){
      errorMessage = "The password you entered is invalid, password must be at least 8 characters";
        return false;
    }

    //consists of only letters and digits
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++) {
      if (!Character.isLetter(x.charAt(i)) && !Character.isDigit(x.charAt(i))) {
          errorMessage = "The password you entered is invalid, password must contain only letters and digits";
        return false;
      }
    }

    //must contain at least two digits
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++) {
      if (Character.isDigit(x.charAt(i))){
        count++;
      }
    }

    if (count >= 2){
      return true;
    }
    else {
        errorMessage = "The password you entered is invalid, password must contain at least two digits";
      return false;
    }
}
}
```

I apologize in advanced in case some of my questions seem rudimentary, any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Did you try `String pass = new String(password);`

Comment: oh wow duh, thank you! put that right after the char[] password line and the error disappeared. Would you happen to know why the call for the errorMessage is getting an error?

Comment: `errorMessage` is not defined within the scope of `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, errorMessage);`

Comment: Because errorMessage is a local variable in your checkPassword method. You cannot access it from within your main method. Moreover, you said you had to work with exceptions. Do not let your checkPassword method return a boolean, instead make it throw a checked exception and catch it in your main method.

Comment: Can anyone comment on what is wrong/missing in my attempt to use the JPasswordField or did i do it correctly? Will a dialog window pop up n have a spot for the user to enter a password with the code i have written?

Answer (score 1):

> how can i take in that password as a string instead

Either `checkPassword(new String(input.getPassword))` or update your method to accept a `char[]` instead of a String.

As for error checking, you should use `throw new ShortPasswordException()`, where you want to throw that error, after you implement a class like `ShortPasswordException extends Exception`, for example.

Then, you can do

```
try { 
    checkPassword();
} catch (ShortPasswordException e) { 
    // TODO: Handle exception
}
```

Tip for the more adventurous: Use a regular expression to check your password requirements. A match of `\d{2}`, for example, means you have 2 consecutive digits.

Answer (score 1):

Two things right off the bat:

(1) Make sure you are importing the correct classes, don't rely on an IDE to do proper imports. You are importing the ActionEvent class from JavaFX, but the framework you are working with is Swing.

Change

```
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
```

To

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
```

I am not very familiar with how nicely JavaFX and Swing play with one another, but using the correct classes typically helps avoid headaches and compile/runtime errors.

(2) A static method in the `java.lang.String` class provides a convenient way to convert a char array into a string. In your `actionPerformed` method, add this:

```
String passStr = String.valueOf(password);
```

E.g.

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // Get the source of the event, we know it is a JPasswordField so we cast it.
    JPasswordField input = (JPasswordField) e.getSource();
    // Get the char array from the input the user typed stored in the input object.
    char[] password = input.getPassword();
    // Convert char[] to String
    String passwordStr = String.valueOf(password);
    if(checkPassword(passwordStr)){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Congradulations, your password follows all the requirements");
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, errorMessage);
    }
}
```